# Logical consequence and tautology question

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $A$ and $B$ be propositional formulas. Show that the logical consequence
$A ⇒ B$ holds if and only if the propositional formula $(A → B)$ is a tautology.

Any help/direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

1. State in words what "the *logical consequence* $A{\implies}B$" *means*.
2. State in words what is *meant* by "the propositional formula $A\to B$ is a *tautology*".

   This wording should refer to "interpretations" and "(truth) values" and such.

   Thus show that whenever one meaning holds, so too does the other.